# How can I achieve to get live events from a http server on an android app? without polling

Tags: java, android, http, networking

I would like to think that polling for updates is not the most efficient way of doing this and latency would be high. 
So is there a better way of achieving this?
Are there any http libraries for that?

Comment: an http server is not designed to push information to a client unless you use either long-polling or websockets.

Comment: by the way I'm using lambda for amazon aws. it looks like  lambda doesn't really go with long-polling since it would be costly to run a function for that long.  I ended up going with mqtt library that can be used from a lambda function to reach amazon IoT for achieving subscribe/publish behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ 
You can handle the message and update the data ( when your app is in foreground or background).

Comment: I know it might be possible to deliver these cloud messages per user basis but is it designed for doing so?

Comment: I think GCM is not designed for your case, just a work around. If you want to do it with GCM, a solution might be : - versioning your data (with a timestamp) - handle a GCM message that contains the updated timestamp - then decide when to pull the updated data inside the app.  Another approach is Firebase, a realtime database. I don't know Firebase that much, I guess it does some kind of pulling and versioning under the hood.